# Raspberry pi2 model B, "Access Point, hostapd" setup issue

Tags: raspberry-pi2, hostapd

Working with Raspberry Pi2, ModelB with below configurations:

```
$ uname -a
```

Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59+ #1047 Sun Oct 29 11:47:10 GMT 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux

```
$ cat /etc/os-release

PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

I have a MediaTek usb-adapter as below:

```
$ lsusb | grep 76
```

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter

When trying to start "hostapd" for creating access-point, the below error is reported:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/hostapd -ddd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random

Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

**Line 2: invalid/unknown driver 'mt7601u'**

1 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'

However, the driver does exist,

```
$ ls /lib/modules/4.9.59+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt7601u

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 126932 Oct 30 14:36 mt7601u.ko
```

Can someone please help point out what is going wrong here ? why is it not able to find the driver ?